# Is there any way to find enclosing resource in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, url-routing, restful-url, actioncontroller

when we write url as /posts/:id/comments, we are mapping comments to posts only can find corresponding comments as:-

```
@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
@comments = @post.comments
```

But lets say comment is having polymorphic association with tags and posts, and can be called as:

```
/posts/:id/comments
/tags/:id/comments
```

Now in Posts#index, i'm unaware of whether it is called with tag or post as enclosing resource, **Is there any method in rails which can find it automatically?**, like in Resources Controller plugin, we have a method called **enclosing_resource** which will provide you the particular post or tag resource and can be used as:-

```
@comments = enclosing_resource.comments
```

I can do it by checking whether params contain post_id or tag_id but it is not the right way and will be not look nice as we increase the polymorphic association with other modules as well.